# Android App is pretty unstable on background service to scan iBeacons

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, estimote

i am working on iBeacons development and i had some problemas with wifi adapter. When the iBeacon scan is running the wifi internet dont work, so i cant request info from internet when an iBeacon was detected. I did tried it on: Moto G, Moto X and Sony Xperia SP.

Another problem is when the scan is running on Android background, i need run this scan all the time to detect new iBeacons? That make the application pretty unstable, maybe because it uses a lot of phone process and memory. Somebody have any information or case about iBeacons Scan on Android background mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of answers:

- Some Android devices have combined WiFi/Bluetooth chips that don't work properly with both radios active.  I know from experience the Moto G is one of those -- it may be true with the others.  (The same devices cannot use Wifi while paired with a Bluetooth speaker either!)  In apps I have developed that do Bluetooth scanning in the background, I detect these devices and detect if WiFi is on, then warn the user that WiFi should be turned off when using the app for proper bluetooth functionality.
- The trick to scanning in the background is to keep the process lightweight and to pause between scans to save battery power.  In my implementations, I have done a scan for a few seconds, then paused for five minutes, then started scanning again, etc.

I've done a lot of work on bluetooth scanning in the background on Android.  If you follow the second tip, the battery drain is tolerable and you should have no stability problems (so long as your code is stable.)